# Display email data in jtable (javamail)

Tags: java

I just started learn java and got assignment to display email in jtable
i got this simple form 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMES5.jpg)

theres no error but also no result, so it confuse me the find where the wrong code, i also had search several case here but mostly not continued

and here is my code

```
    public class MailInbox extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     public void MailInbox(String host, String storeType, String user,
          String password) 
    {
          try {
      //create properties field
      Properties properties = new Properties();

      properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
      properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
      Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
      Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

      store.connect(host, user, password);

      //create the folder object and open it
      Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
      emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

      // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array 
      Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

      for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
         String[] heads = {"Subject", "Sender", "Send Date", "Content"};
                Object[][] data = {

                        {messages[i].getSubject(), (InternetAddress.toString(messages[i].getFrom())), messages[i].getReceivedDate(), messages[i].getContent()}


                };
       jTable1 (heads, data);
      }

      //close the store and folder objects
      emailFolder.close(false);
      store.close();

      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   } 

    public MailInbox() {
        initComponents();

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String host = "pop.gmail.com";
      String mailStoreType = "pop3";
      String username = "mail";
      String password = "password";

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   



    private void jTable1(String[] heads, Object[][] data) {
        this.jTable1 = jTable1;
    }

}
```

Please help, Thank you very much

Comment: if you used exacly this code, it has syntax errors. main method should be closed. Also there are nothing in main class. This code does nothing as i can see.

Comment: 1. As mBogaz pointed out, your main method is unfinished.  You need to create an instance of your class and call its setVisible method. 2. Your `jtable1` method does nothing. You probably wanted to use the method arguments to create a new DefaultTableModel and pass it to your JTable’s setModel method. 3. You have not created a JTable or JScrollPane. You need to do that, and you need to add them to your JFrame.

Comment: 4. `new Object[][] data` is the data for *all the rows of the table.*  Every time you examine a message, you are replacing *all the rows of the table* with data containing only that message.  Instead of an array , try creating a Vector *outside your loop,* then adding an element to it for each message.  Update your JTable after your loop is finished, not inside the loop.